# What is the Generics Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I'm confused about the Generics class.

What is the purpose of the this class? Examples of use?

Comment: Did you read any tutorials? That should be a better way to get started.

Comment: Not to retype from MDSN - a very good article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx

Comment: Please read a good book or tutorial, this site is not supposed to answer questions on basic programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f.aspx

> Generic classes encapsulate operations that are not specific to a
>   particular data type. The most common use for generic classes is with
>   collections like linked lists, hash tables, stacks, queues, trees, and
>   so on. Operations such as adding and removing items from the
>   collection are performed in basically the same way regardless of the
>   type of data being stored.